# $\alpha$ for uniform convergence $\sum \frac{x^\alpha}{1+n^2x^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

Find $\alpha \ge 0$ such that following is uniformly convergent on (1) $[0,1]$ and (2) $[0,\infty)$
$$\sum \frac{x^\alpha}{1+n^2x^2}$$

I thought about using $1+n^2x^2\ge 2nx$ but cant conclude anything from here as we only get $\frac{x^\alpha}{1+n^2x^2} \leq \frac{x^\alpha}{2nx}$. But RHS is divergent.

By observing [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/kyotp0pdjm), it appears that $\alpha \geq 1$ for case 1.

Comment: Thanks, I thought about this but cant conclude anything from here? as we only get $\frac{x^\alpha}{1+n^2x^2} \leq \frac{x^\alpha}{2nx}$. But RHS is divergent.

Comment: $\alpha$ doesn't matter because you can just pull out $x^\alpha$

Comment: @ZacharySelk well this is true if we sum over $n$ (instead of $x$), but it is not given by OP.

Comment: Also it appears that above series cant be uniformly convergent on closed interval starting at zero as at $x=0$ it will simply diverge, no matter what is $\alpha$

Comment: It diverges for $x=0$????????????????????????

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I overlooked $x^\alpha$ after taking it out of summation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For $\alpha >0$ the series obviously converges pointwise to $0$ for $x=0$, but fails to converge uniformly for $x \in [0,b]$ or $x\in[0,\infty)$  if $\alpha \in (0,1]$ since,

$$\sup_{x \in (0,b]}\left|\sum_{k = n+1}^\infty \frac{x^\alpha}{1 + k^2x^2}\right| =  \sup_{x \in (0,b]}\sum_{k = n+1}^\infty \frac{x^\alpha}{1 + k^2x^2} \\ >\sup_{x \in (0,b]}\sum_{k = n+1}^{2n}\frac{x^\alpha}{1 + k^2x^2} \\> \frac{n x^\alpha}{1 + 4n^2x^2}$$

Taking $x = 1/n$ we have if $\alpha \leqslant 1$,

$$\sup_{x \in (0,b]}\left|\sum_{k = n+1}^\infty \frac{x^\alpha}{1 + n^2x^2}\right| > \frac{n^{1-\alpha}}{5} \not\to 0$$

I'll leave it to you to show when the series converges uniformly.

Comment: Why do you say "fails to converge uniformly for $x \in [0,b]$ or $x\in[0,\infty)$" when the first implies the second?

Comment: @zhw:  A very astute observation.  I was simply making reference to the (1) and (2) dichotomy of the OPs question.

Comment: Oh I see. I hadn't even noticed the two parts